# Trying to bind Html form with dynamic rows of data saved in database

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a form where some input value is there in two table and one of the table has one  row  where dynamic row can be generated and then value could be entered and then saved to database.

Now I want to retrieve the those value and bind in a html form and based on the number of dynamic rows of data saved in database Iwant to bind html form row also.I am Passing `Tdc_no` as parameter in proc.

Html form where data need to be bind

```
<body>    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dvContents">

        <table style="margin-left:700px;width:15%;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;"><tr><td style="font-size:12pt"><b>TDC No.</b></td><td><label runat="server" id='Tdc_No'></label></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:12pt"><b>Revision</b></td><td><label  runat="server" id='Revision'></label></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table style="width:90%;margin-left:70px;font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;">
            <tr style="font-size:12pt;background-color:yellow;">
                <td colspan="2"><b>Wire Dimensions</b></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:large"><b>Standard Sizes & Tolerances</b></td>
                <td>
                    <table id='WireDimTbl'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Size Range Min(mm)</th>
                                <th>Size Range Max (mm)</th>
                                <th>Tolerance, mm (-)</th>
                                <th>Tolerance, mm (+) mm</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Data coming from database
Two tables are there i joined it through proc and data is returning from proc now i want to bind it with html form. 
Table Tdc_product1
TDC_NO  REVISION
7y  1

Table Prop_Detail

```
TDC_NO  ROWNO   PROP_NAME   TDC_PROPERTY
-------------------------------------------
7y      1       sizMin      2
7y      1       sizeMax     3
7y      1       tolMin      1
7y      1       tolMax      2
7y      2       sizMin      4
7y      2       sizeMax     5
7y      2       tolMin      6
7y      2       tolMax      7
```

Joined with proc

```
Create proc abc
(
    @tdc_no varchar(10) = null
) As
Begin
    Select * 
    FROM tdc_product1 p 
    INNER JOIN Prop_detail pd ON p.tdc_no =pd.tdc_no
    WHERE  p.tdc_no=@tdc_no    
End
```

It will return  data in this format

```
TDC_NO  REVISION    TDC_NO  ROWNO   PROP_NAME   TDC_PROPERTY
-------------------------------------------------------------
7y      1           7y      1       sizMin      2
7y      1           7y      1       sizeMax     3
7y      1           7y      1       tolMin      1
7y      1           7y      1       tolMax      2
7y      1           7y      2       sizMin      4
7y      1           7y      2       sizeMax     5
7y      1           7y      2       tolMin      6
7y      1           7y      2       tolMax      7
```

Comment: @Dhaval Please arrange the data according to row it has been distorted

Comment: Your code suggests that this is **NOT ORACLE**; why did you tag it so? Was it by mistake?

Comment: @Littlefoot k will update